# android photo modification time gets changed

Tags: android, image, file

I noticed that the modification time of photos is different from the creation time.
It can be similar, but mostly is different.
Usually, it's a 1 minute differene but in some cases even it can be even an hour.

My problem is that something causes the files to change/modified and I don't know what it is.
Perhaps it's the camera app that uses the creation time as a timestamp but actually finishes the writing a minute later? (perhaps after having the location data saved?)

I can't explain the 1 hour difference though.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one of the apps installed on my device modifies the time of the photo.

When testing on a fresh factory reset phone, the photos time stay the same as the created time.

When we'll know the app that modifies the time of the photo, I'll post it here.

I just hope that it isn't changing the photos themselves and just "lightly" touches them.

Answer (score 2):

Is it by chance that you also have QuickPic installed? Is it an Xperia phone? Got the same problem here.. Have run a binary diff and although the date has changed the files are identical. Still it is annoying. f.e. exif data says

```
Image timestamp : 2012:09:07 23:33:27
```

but stat gives

```
Modify: 2012-09-07 23:33:28.000000000 +0200
```

on the file synced before and

```
Modify: 2012-09-08 00:33:28.000000000 +0200
```

about same file on the phone, which is wrong. This just shouldn't happen. Huh?!

Comment: Indeed in the past, when it happened, I had quickpick installed. It's not an Xperia. I think the problem happened lately again but I didn't have QuickPic installed.

Comment: mmh... well it's very strange and disrupts any serious data backup endeavor (rsync --update with/without --remove-files).. will continue to investigate this.